# notification manager doesn't work in Kitkat

Tags: android

`Alarm manager` doesn't work on my cell phone "Kitkat" but it does work on Emulator GenyMotion API 25 
I wonder what's the wrong?

I call this in main activity

```
PollReceiver.scheduleAlarms(getApplicationContext());
```

And here are the classes involved:

```
package com.hema.engshow;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.SystemClock;

import java.util.Calendar;

import static android.content.Context.ALARM_SERVICE;

public class PollReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static AlarmManager mAlarmManager;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent i) {
        scheduleAlarms(ctxt);
    }

    static void scheduleAlarms(Context ctxt) {
        Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,14);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,47);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,10);

        Intent intent=new Intent(ctxt,AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent broadcast=   PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt,
                101,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        mAlarmManager=(AlarmManager) ctxt.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,mCalendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,broadcast);
    }
}
```

And this is the alarmReciever:

```
package com.hema.engshow;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.text.format.Time;

import java.util.logging.FileHandler;

import static android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;

/**
 * Created by hema on 7/30/2017.
 */

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {   
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("Demo App Notification")
                .setContentText("New Notification From Demo App..")
                .setTicker("New Message Alert!")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);


        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
}
```

And finally here is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.hema.engshow">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Vocab">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <receiver android:name="PollReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and the gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hema.engshow"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
}
```

I hope someone helps me figure out the problem because I searched everywhere but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calobj.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calobj.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        } else{
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calobj.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }
```

There are some method changes for AlarmManager for different API levels try the above code, its for one time alarm you can find the same for repeating alarm in Android Documentation